# How to stop ActiveMQ 's 'Queue' to stop receiving messages

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Is it possible to stop a specific Queue of ActiveMQ after it has consumed say 100 messages for 5sec and after 5sec again it will restart and start receiving messages ?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ has some flow control but mostly on memory constraints.

Try using some router software like that, such as the [Apache Camel Throttler](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html)

I'm not sure that you can do exactly what you ask out of the box but similar things. Or you can add what you want with some logic. Note that Camel is [bundled](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) in most ActiveMQ distributions.

Then you would probably setup one "from" queue where the application writes messages and route it though ActiveMQ to one "to" queue where the consumer reads messages.